# How can I customize string:message in spring to allow for internal variables in the message.proporties file?

Tags: java, spring

While using spring:message tag I found the need to create internal variables the message.proporties file. Specifically what I was hoping to do was something like this:

favoriteFood = My favorite food is $bestfood$

givemeFood = Please give me $bestfood$

bestfood = carrots

What I would like to do is define variables inside of the message.proporties file that can reference eachother. The reason for doing this would be to eliminate the need to change a value in multiple places whenever a change was made. In the example if my favorite food changed I could just alter the "bestfood" value rather than having to change the string for favoriteFood and givemeFood.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Why the `javascript` tag?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as create a variable inside a string and change it dynamically, besides that, strings in Java are immutable, and you would need to create a new one anyway.
Looks like you are searching for something like "two-way data binding" that we can find in AngularJS for example, but in that case, we are binding a variable to a html element content, far different when using a Java string.

I would suggest to save your property like:

`message=My name is {0} and I am {1}`

Then use [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-):

`MessageFormat.format(yourProperty, "Flavio", "cool");`

Resulting in:

`My name is Flavio and I am cool`